# What is the best method for cleaning up Audit Tables in OroCommerce 4.1?

Tags: orocommerce

My oro_audit table is 4.007.603 and oro_audit_field 27.211.076 records big. I need to purge some old records and was hoping to get some of the best known methods for this task. Can i delete them directly from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, there are no methods to automatically remove old audit data.

You can purge old records manually from the database tables or create a [cron command](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/cron/#dev-cookbook-system-cron-create-commands) to run it on time basis.